# Bootstrap vertical column ordering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**xs** layout shows as expected but how to pull *sidebar* up to *navigation* to remove gap between them in **lg** layout

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9">
        navigation
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9 col-lg-pull-3">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9">
        sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

XS

```
navigation
---
content
---
sidebar
```

LG

```
content    | navigation
           | sidebar
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Pn8r4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the position of the `.c-g` (content) col to absolute on large screens?

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .c-g {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/fHTPK/3/)**

Note that you can use the Bootstrap variable for the screen width if doing this in LESS:

`@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }`